How does SQLite3 implement its 'secure-delete' without the ability to randomly write file in the middle?

When secure_delete is on, SQLite overwrites deleted content with zeros. 1

How could SQLite 'overwrite deleted content with zeros'? These
deleted content might be in the middle of the database file.
Does SQLite implement this mechanism by rewriting every bytes after
the deleted content? This way, it might introduce massive disk IO.
For example, when the deleted content has 2GB data after it, this
secure-delete process would require rewriting all of the following
2GB data to the filesystem. That would take a lot of time.

imho it's not exactly clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "after the deleted content", and why should writing zeros "in the middle of the database file" be a problem to begin with?

Do not include solution to question please (post a separate answer instead).

When the option is on, SQlite scribblles zeros into the RAM copy of the blocks where the deleted data used to be, and affected other blocks of the BTREE structure. With the option off it just leaves the old data, after marking that part of the block as free for re-use.  Scribbling zeros into RAM is relatively inexpensive.
Then, the "dirty" (changed) block gets pushed to SSD / HDD via the usual mechanisms. Whether or not the option is on doesn't change how the block must be handled after it is changed. And pushing data  to SSD / HDD is far far far slower than writing to RAM. So the difference is hard to measure.
If you don't turn on the option, a cybercreep might be able to dump your .sqlite file and find vestiges of deleted rows.

It probably makes little difference whether secure_delete is on or off as in either case it is the changed required pages that have to be written to the file.
You may wish to refer to https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html
Perhaps consider the following (which equates to about 1.5GB i.e. 417826 pages at 4k per page).
The end result after deleting ALL rows of the single table is that the page count is reduced to 4.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, v1 TEXT, v2 TEXT);
WITH cte(i) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT i+1 FROM cte LIMIT 100000000)
INSERT INTO t1 (v1,v2) SELECT 'XXX','YYY' FROM cte;

PRAGMA page_count;
PRAGMA secure_delete;
PRAGMA secure_delete = 'off';
PRAGMA secure_delete;
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id % 2;
PRAGMA page_count;
SELECT * FROM t1;
PRAGMA secure_delete;
PRAGMA secure_delete = 'on';
PRAGMA secure_delete;
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE NOT id % 2;
PRAGMA page_count;
SELECT count(*) FROM t1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;

When run the insert takes about 74 seconds:-
WITH cte(i) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT i+1 FROM cte LIMIT 100000000)
INSERT INTO t1 (v1,v2) SELECT 'XXX','YYY' FROM cte
> Affected rows: 100000000
> Time: 74.017s

The first delete of 50% of the rows when secure_delete is off takes about 40 seconds:-
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id % 2
> Affected rows: 50000000
> Time: 40.71s

Whilst the second delete of the remaining rows with secure_delete on takes a little less at around 38 seconds:-
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE NOT id % 2
> Affected rows: 50000000
> Time: 34.383s

The timings are reliant upon the execution environment.
It should also be noted that the logging mode may affect timings as could other changeable parameters such as, for example, the page_size.
The above code could be adapted as required, it is intended to be a very basic test.

it is uncanny (or not) that the time taken for the deletes is similar to the time taken to insert.


Notice that secure_delete will also overwrite fts5- and btree-index pages, which adds to the additional "workload". Also notice that overwriting with zero-bytes may have no measurable performance impact at all, because the on-disk page has to be touched anyway and the i/o-subsystem might write the entire page, so there is no performance downside with secure_delete. Your mileage may strongly vary with the underlying i/o subsystem, though.
